# Executing a query crashing the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to execute a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_fdhosts;
```

Against MS SQL Server 2008.

I'm connected as `sa`, but when executing I'm getting following:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

and I become disconnected.

What am I missing? Am I not allowed to run query against `sys` schema? Even with `sa` user?

EDIT:

I do have both servers installed:

[image]

EDIT2:

Here is my services. I thin only 2008 is running.

[image]

Comment: what OS is the server installed on and what is the result of: SELECT @@version;

Comment: presumably you've ruled out the obivous and done a full server reboot? Just fyi I can select from this dmv fine (using 2016 & 2019)

Comment: This is nothing to do with permissions. It is an unhandled error in the SQL Server code. Maybe a known issue but as they have closed down Connect site not easy to say. What is your `@@VERSION` - are you missing any SP or CU that might have a fix for this?

Comment: @DaFi4, it is Windows 8.1 and the result is `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.1.6241.0 (X64)

Comment: @Stu, I just rebooted the whole machine and still getting the same error. Any idea?

Comment: @MartinSmith, I don't know if I'm missing smth - how could I check? Maybe I installed an update that broke it?

Comment: In your question you state Sql Server 2012, but your comment above says Sql Server 2008. I don't have anything that old to test on, it's about time you upgraded ;-)

Comment: @Stu, I guess I have somewhere version 2012, because the connect dialog displays it. Any idea on switching?

Comment: You need to get your `@@VERSION` and compare it with the builds here https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/ to see if there is a later build available

Comment: @Stu, Any pointers on how to switch to SQL Server 2012? I do have it installed..

Comment: @Stu, please see the edit - I just need to run the newer version of the server.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I think I have a newer version than that table displays...

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?

Comment: @MartinSmith, See my reply above to DaFi4.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I've ever seen zero search results for a SQL Server build number before. I agree then doesn't look like you are missing any patches - I guess 10.1.6241.0 must have been some security fix delivered well after official support ended, 2008 is well out of support so probably you should consider upgrading anyway, otherwise if there are any stack dumps generated you can try and do some stack dump analysis yourself to see if that gives any clues

Comment: @MartinSmith, as the screenshot in OP shows I do have version 2012 installed. So now the question becomes - how do I run version 2012? Or check if its already running and connect to it?

Comment: 2012 will be installed as a named instance - check it's running under `services` and just connect to it using `machine name\instance` or its `ip address:port` if it's configured to use its own port. [Multiple instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/work-with-multiple-versions-and-instances-of-sql-server)

Comment: @Stu, see my second edit. I think only 2008 version is running.